# How to trigger a jenkins build when there is a github pull request

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How do I configure jenkins to trigger a build whenever there is a pull request to a branch on a repository.

For ex, I have a develop branch.
So, whenever there is a pull request to this branch, I have to trigger a build in jenkins (run some integration test case before merging the PR).

If the build fails, I need to send a mail to the person who broke the build.

How do I achieve this in Jenkins.

Comment: A pull request? Or a push request?

Comment: A pull request. I'm one of the users with admin privileges to a repository.So, here whenever someone sends a pull request to a particular branch in this repo, I need to trigger a build with this before merging.

Answer (score 2):

Install [GitHub pull request builder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin). This plugin builds pull requests in Github and report results at Github PR.

Comment: The current version of GitHub pull request builder (v 1.41.0) comes with a "Warning: This plugin version may not be safe to use".  Would you still recommend using the plugin despite the security warning? (The warning is related to GitHub access tokens getting stored in build.xml)